# Trigger data dog alert when metric is true in consecutive time period - Data Dog

Tags: alert, monitor, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I was trying to configure data dog alerts for my server. I send a value 1 when the server is up and value 0 when the server is down every minute. I set up a simple monitor with the condition min
Evaluate minimum over last 10 minutes.

[image]

So in this condition if the server is down atleast once in last 10 mins then notification is sent.

What I want to achieve is, suppose the server is done in last 10 mins and the server is again down in next 10 mins then only trigger the alert. Suppose in 1st 10 mins server was down but it auto recovered and in next 10 mins it is up then I don't want alert to be triggered. When the server is down for 2 consecutive 10 mins, alert should be triggered ?

How can I set up these metric condition in datadog ?